# I cannot get 3rd juicebox gallery to show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

In the "work" section of my site, I cannot seem to get the 3rd gallery (Commercial) to show up.

Link - http://www.alliedouglass.com/20120521_index.html#work

You'll notice that if you start on the "Journalism" slide and then click on "Commercial" it appears briefly but then vanishes.

The photo gallery plugin is http://juicebox.net/ and content slider is flexslider.

This is my first website, so i'd like to apologize for the amount of errors in the code, and also for the slow page loading. These are all things I'm currently addressing, or am at least attempting to.

Comment: Works on chrome and ff for me.

Comment: Yeah, I found that if I add an additional 4th Gallery in the html, the 3rd gallery appears. Obviously this is not my desired resolution. I imagine it has something to do w/ my flexslider javascript, but I'm not well versed enough locate the problem.